# How to weight my partial credit for multiple choice

Tags: probability

I teach a large enrollment course, and as such I give multiple choice quizzes and exams. Last semester I started using a method to award partial credit that allows students to select two answers (usually there are 5 choices), essentially allowing them to hedge their bet. There is only ever one correct option for a question, so this doubles their chance that they choose the right answer (and then earn partial credit).

I use the following grading scheme:

```
Correct answer:
1 answer selected: 1 point
2 answers selected: 0.7 points

Incorrect answer:
1 answer selected: 0 points
2 answers selected: -0.25 points
```

As you can see, this encourages students to guess when they can narrow down the choices. But it discourages students from just choosing two answers for every question, because of the -0.25 cost if neither option they pick is correct.

My question here: is there a way to evaluate my point breakdown and determine if it is accomplishing the goal I've set out to do? Ideally, someone that selected two options at random for each question, should end up with a negative score (lets say 20 question on a exam).

Happy to provide further information/details if they are needed.

Comment: Well, right off the top of my head, a student who does nothing but guess has a positive expected score... (they earn $0.70$ points with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and earn $-0.25$ point with probability $\frac{1}{2}$; therefore they should have an expected score of $\frac{1}{2}( 0.70 - 0.25) = 0.225$ points per question).

Comment: @XanderHenderson 5 choices, not 4... but the conclusion is still true.

Comment: Anecdotally, if I were a student in your course, I would hate this format because it increases (potentially stressful) decisionmaking during the test: not only do I have to pick which answer I think is best, I also have to decide how confident I am in my first choice vs. my second choice so I can decide whether I should hedge my bet or not!

Comment: @Y.Forman this might be true, but overwhelmingly I've had positive response from students. If you are stressed about the decision, then just take it like a normal scantron and ignore the extra option (it's specifically made so that you can take it like normal without any change). Students strongly dislike all/nothing when they were stuck between two choices. This alleviates that problem (some), without me needing to do a free response exam for 100 students where I could give partial credit.

Comment: @JM I trust you know what you're doing and obviously there's no reason my personal feelings should be representative of anything. Without having actually been in the situation, I think offhand I probably would just take it like normal, but I'd have a slight nagging feeling that maybe I would have done better had I hedged my bets on a couple of questions. I could definitely see why this format would appeal to other people, though.

Comment: @Y.Forman Oi.  I missed that part.  But yeah, the same conclusion holds, with slightly different numbers.

Comment: J M:  I would love to provide more input on this, and think that there are some interesting ideas here, but I don't think that the kind of input that I would like to give is appropriate for MSE.  Would you mind cross-posting this on the Math Ed SE, with, perhaps, a slightly tweaked question (to emphasize the teaching aspect a bit more)?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sure, is it ok to reference this question? I've never "purposely" posted a question like this :)

Comment: @JM It can't hurt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your last question, we can compute the expected score on each question, given the strategy is choosing two answers at random. There's probability $0.4$ that this strategy will pick the correct answer, and probability $0.6$ that this strategy will pick the wrong answer, so the expected value is $$0.4\cdot 0.7 + 0.6 \cdot (-0.25) = 0.28 - 0.15 = 0.13$$
So this strategy won't, on average, give a negative score; it will give on average $0.13$ per question.

On the other hand, a strategy of guessing one answer at random will give
$$ 0.2 \cdot 1 + 0.8 \cdot 0 = 0.2 + 0 = 0.2$$
So it is better for the student, if the student is guessing randomly, to guess one answer than it is to guess two.

Let's say the student is (correctly) confident one choice is wrong and guesses randomly among the other 4. Then the probabilities come out to the following: 2-choice strategy:
$$ 0.5 \cdot 0.7 + 0.5 \cdot (-0.25) = 0.225$$
1-choice strategy:
$$0.25 \cdot 1 + 0.75 \cdot 0 = 0.25$$
So it's still a little better to choose 1 answer.

If the student is (correctly) confident two choices are wrong and guesses randomly among the other 3, the 2-choice strategy gives:
$$ \frac23 \cdot 0.7 + \frac13 \cdot (-0.25) \approx 0.38 $$
and the 1-choice strategy:
$$ \frac13 \cdot 1 + \frac23 \cdot 0 \approx 0.33 $$
So if the student can narrow down to three choices, it becomes advantageous to choose two of those three at random.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I think I can apply this into a spreadsheet and tweak the values to achieve the results I'd like, thank you!